# Uncompress column if different column is 1, but not if it's 0

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a column (BLOB) that may be compressed, and another column with either a 1 or zero that indicates weather the column is compressed. I'd like to uncompress it (or do some other operation) and return if it is compressed, and simply return the value if it's not.  Is this possible with a single SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(another_column_with_either_a_1_or_zero = 1,
          UNCOMPRESS(a_column_BLOB_that_may_be_compressed),
          a_column_BLOB_that_may_be_compressed) AS definitely_uncompressed
FROM a_table_who_shall_not_be_named
```

Comment: Oh, cool! If statements are powerful.

Comment: Yes! It's worth reading about [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) and [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) and other builtin functions and control-flow syntax. Practice with them so they come to mind when you need them.

Comment: I was able to find information on IF, but no examples included dynamic returns

Comment: Often you see SQL queries that use only bare columns in the select-list, but in fact you can use any expression you want.